# Positioning a 'line' near a header, that independent of the header size, length, padding or margin

Tags: css

I want to obtain a header like in the image below[image]

I can obtained using position absolute, but this depends on  the header characteristics, like margin,padding.

I'm interested to have the result below, indifferent of the header size,length , padding or margin. I need something that is supported also by older browsers like IE10, IE11.

Comment: if it's a header of h1 tag means, it will be `display:block`. so if you want the line next to it means, you have to position it. You can try the same using after pseudo element also.

Comment: can u elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:after` and create there the line
Learn:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

```css
div{
color:red;
}
div:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>Header</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: using top the position depends on the header/div height, and I want to be independent